# Antiproton production threshold

Tags: particle-physics, kinematics, antimatter, large-hadron-collider

Why is the antiproton threshold on [cern](http://accelconf.web.cern.ch/accelconf/ipac2012/papers/weppd030.pdf) 6* m_p and on [uspas](http://uspas.fnal.gov/materials/12MSU/rellect.pdf) it is 7 * m_p?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the first one is about kinetic energy, :

> [requires a minimum](http://accelconf.web.cern.ch/accelconf/ipac2012/papers/weppd030.pdf) *kinetic proton  energy*  in  the  laboratory  system  above  the  pbar  threshold of 6 mpc2 = 5.6 GeV

italics mine

And the second one is about total Energy , $E_{beam}$ which means the mass term is included in [the energy.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html)

[image: rest mass]

If you solve for E, the rest mass has to be added, ${(pc)}^2$  is the kinetic energy part.

See also [this homework](http://www.hep.wisc.edu/~yli/Web_Folder/Courses/535%20Particle%20Physics/homework/set2a05.pdf) problem, that has both.

Comment: Also the energy required is actually two times the energy of the antiproton because everytime an antiproton is made, a corresponding proton is also made to conserve baryon number. So the energy is roughly 1.8 Gev to make the antiproton-proton pair.